# How do I turn a link into an image to embed?

Tags: php, jquery, embed, oembed

I am attempting to create some functionality on beta.peaksneak.com where users can basically journalize. To do this I want them to be able to add images, videos, quotes, and links to a journal entry.

I found out that you can use [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) to embed videos, and images/quotes are easy.

Is there a script for embedding links and auto-capturing a large image from the link to use for embed purposes? For example, on Facebook, when I paste a link into a comment, it automatically generates an image and text (probably from meta tags and the first large image it can find).

Comment: A site that does this is embed.ly - obviously I am looking for a non-subscription method or coding my own.

Comment: There isn't any reason to bold the question paragraph. `:)`

Comment: The solution will depend on your server's OS. Have you tried Google "render html to image"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try https://github.com/starfishmod/jquery-oembed-all for your oembed stuff - it has a lot of providers and is client side only if that is what you are looking for?